# Enable editing on protected excel file

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am trying to edit excel file (.xlsx) using closedXML. It throws exception after i edit and save it which says {"An item with the same key has already been added. Key: B2501"}. I don't have any other instance opened of excel workbook open.

I am guessing it might be because its protected file i am unable to Save or Save As.

Does anyone have any insight on how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  public void deleteUnusedRowFromExcel(string filePath, string sheetName, string strfileName)
    {
        int rowCount = 0;
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(filePath))
        {
            IXLWorksheet xLWorksheet;
            if (sheetName != "")
            {
                xLWorksheet = wb.Worksheet(sheetName);
            }
            else
            {
                xLWorksheet = wb.Worksheet(1);
            }
            rowCount = xLWorksheet.RowsUsed().Count() == 0 ? 0 : xLWorksheet.RowsUsed().Count() - 1;

          
            foreach (IXLRow row in xLWorksheet.RowsUsed())
            {
                string ab = row.Cell(2).GetString();
                if (row.Cell(2).GetString() == "")
                {
                    row.Delete();
                    break;
                }
            }
            wb.SaveAs(strfileName);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve? 1) Editing this 'protected' sheet ?  2) Saving this sheet ? Please specify at which line you are getting the error (after 'edit' or after 'save'...)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ClosedXML? If so, then this might be a bug and I would appreciate it if you can log it on the Github repo with full issue template populated. (I'm a ClosedXML maintainer).